# Usage of Carrage return in Prepared Statement

Tags: java, oracle, prepared-statement

I have a string

```
String temp = "I am bharat \n sripuram"
```

I tried to insert the same in Oracle Database using `PreparedStatement`.
But when I see the same on my web page, it is coming in Single line "I am bharat sripuram". The carriage Return is missing. Can someone suggest me how to retrieve the same using carriage return.

Comment: Can you show the code that displays this string?

Comment: The database doesn't know what "\n" is. But it does know what CHAR(13) is.

Comment: @DrewKennedy: The DB may not, but Java certainly does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Gah. I totally missed the part about the output being viewed on a web page. I need more booze.

Comment: It's not related to viewing am concerned, It's saving into Database the string "\n".

Answer (score 3):

You haven't given us very much information, but taking a wild stab at it:

If you output the string to the HTML as-is, without doing any processing, it's exactly like writing this HTML (I'll put it in a `p`):

```
<p>I am bharat 
sripuram</p>
```

Which is displayed by a web browser as:

> I am bharat sripuram

...because all whitespace in HTML is treated as a single space, including carriage returns and newlines.

Example:

```html
<p>I am bharat 
sripuram</p>
```

If you want a line break in HTML, use `<br>` (or separate the content into separate elements). Example:

```html
<p>I am bharat<br>sripuram</p>
```

Comment: The is not something related to Display, It's something with Escape sequence characters like "\n". How can we store this info into Database using PreparedStatement ?

Comment: @Bharat: If you took your `temp`, as it is in your question, and did `ps.setString(paramNumber, temp);` where `ps` is a `PreparedStatement` for an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or whatever and executed the statement, it would get stored correctly, and come back correctly when you do a query later and retrieve it from a `ResultSet` via `.getString`. That's why I mentioned display, because with what little you showed, `temp` **would** get stored correctly.

Comment: Now you are there, I have explicitly given "\n" in the string and stored ps.setString(paramNumber, temp), But Still am getting in a Straight line. That's the problem.

Comment: @Bharat: Well, you need to debug it to find out when it's getting lost. I guarantee you that it's not the DB dropping it, and as I said above I suspect the problem is when you're displaying it. If you set a breakpoint on the line of code *retrieving* it from the DB and examine the string, you'll see the line break there.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :-

String temp="'I am bharat'||char(13)||char(10)|| sripuram'" ;

Note the use of apostrophe within quotation marks.

char(13) is carriage return and char(10) is linefeed character.

This will insert a newline in database. For your web page , you will need to insert  wherever you want newline .